# Problem With Simple PL/SQL Program

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, ora-00942

Here is my simple PL/SQL program:

```
DECLARE

    CURSOR c1 is
        SELECT typ, specifikacia_typu, spz FROM Auta
            WHERE (substr(spz, 1, 2) = 'KE' OR substr(spz, 1, 2) = 'KS') AND ROWNUM <= 2;
    CURSOR c2 is
        SELECT typ, specifikacia_typu, spz FROM Auta
            WHERE substr(spz, 1, 2) <> 'KE' AND substr(spz, 1, 2) <> 'KS';
    my_typ CHAR(10);
    my_specifikacia_typu CHAR(15);
    my_spz CHAR(8);

BEGIN

    -- vytovirt potrebne tabulky pre kosicke a nekosicke auta
    CREATE TABLE Kosicke (
    typ CHAR(10),
    specifikacia_typu CHAR(15),
    spz CHAR(8)
    );
    CREATE TABLE Ostatne (
    typ CHAR(10),
    specifikacia_typu CHAR(15),
    spz CHAR(8)
    );

    -- prve dve auta z Kosic vlozit do tabulky Kosicke
    OPEN c1;
    FOR i IN 1..2 LOOP
        FETCH c1 INTO my_typ, my_specifikacia_typu, my_spz;
        EXIT WHEN c1%NOTFOUND;
        INSERT INTO Kosice VALUES(my_typ, my_specifikacia_typu, my_spz);
        COMMIT;
    END LOOP;
    CLOSE c1;

    -- auta, ktore nie su z Kosic vlozit do tabulky Ostatne
    OPEN c2;
    LOOP
        FETCH c2 INTO my_typ, my_specifikacia_typu, my_spz;
        EXIT WHEN c2%NOTFOUND;
        INSERT INTO Ostatne VALUES(my_typ, my_specifikacia_typu, my_spz);
        COMMIT;
    END LOOP;
    CLOSE c1;

END;
/
```

When I run it Oracle 10g Express Edition, I get this error:

```
ORA-06550: line 16, column 5:
PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "CREATE" when expecting one of the following:

   begin case declare exit for goto if loop mod null pragma
   raise return select update while with 
     <<
   close current delete fetch lock insert open rollback
   savepoint set sql execute commit forall merge pipe

1. DECLARE
2.     
3.     CURSOR c1 is
```

I'm not sure where the problem is and this is my first program I wrote in PL/SQL so I'm a little lost. I have used this example programs from Oracle website to write this program: http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B10501_01/appdev.920/a96624/a_samps.htm#563

EDIT:

Also, when I create the tables outside the program first and then run the program, I get this error:

```
ORA-06550: line 17, column 21:
PL/SQL: ORA-00942: table or view does not exist
ORA-06550: line 17, column 9:
PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored

1. DECLARE    
2.     CURSOR c1 is
3.         SELECT typ, specifikacia_typu, spz FROM Auta
```

Which doesn't make sense because table "Auta" exists, all tables used in the program do exist.

Comment: You should post your answer then, and please don't edit the title to state that the issue is solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so just to let you know how I solved the problem (I have already solved it before anyone aswered).

First, I created the tables outside of the program with a normal SQL queries:

```
CREATE TABLE Kosicke (
typ CHAR(10),
specifikacia_typu CHAR(15),
spz CHAR(8)
);
CREATE TABLE Ostatne (
typ CHAR(10),
specifikacia_typu CHAR(15),
spz CHAR(8)
);
```

And I edited the program like this (it works already):

```
DECLARE

    CURSOR c1 is
        SELECT typ, specifikacia_typu, spz FROM Auta
            WHERE (substr(spz, 1, 2) = 'KE' OR substr(spz, 1, 2) = 'KS') AND ROWNUM <= 2;
    CURSOR c2 is
        SELECT typ, specifikacia_typu, spz FROM Auta
            WHERE substr(spz, 1, 2) <> 'KE' AND substr(spz, 1, 2) <> 'KS';
    my_typ CHAR(10);
    my_specifikacia_typu CHAR(15);
    my_spz CHAR(8);

BEGIN

    /* prve dve auta z Kosic vlozit do tabulky Kosicke */
    OPEN c1;
    FOR i IN 1..2 LOOP
        FETCH c1 INTO my_typ, my_specifikacia_typu, my_spz;
        EXIT WHEN c1%NOTFOUND;
        INSERT INTO Kosicke VALUES(my_typ, my_specifikacia_typu, my_spz);
        COMMIT;
    END LOOP;
    CLOSE c1;

    /* auta, ktore nie su z Kosic vlozit do tabulky Ostatne */
    OPEN c2;
    LOOP
        FETCH c2 INTO my_typ, my_specifikacia_typu, my_spz;
        EXIT WHEN c2%NOTFOUND;
        INSERT INTO Ostatne VALUES(my_typ, my_specifikacia_typu, my_spz);
        COMMIT;
    END LOOP;
    CLOSE c2;

END;
/
```

Comment: It works, but it is still the wrong approach.  The explicit cursors are an unnecessary overhead, and the in-loop COMMIT statements can cause ORA-1002 exceptions.  You will get away with it when you are only inserting two rows, but not with larger volumes.

Comment: APC and other posters are right, not quite sure why you'd use 2 cursors like this in what can be done as 2 insert statements.  If you're still following the thread Richard...whats wrong with just doing : insert into ostane (SELECT typ, specifikacia_typu, spz FROM Auta 
            WHERE substr(spz, 1, 2) <> 'KE' AND substr(spz, 1, 2) <> 'KS'; 
)            then repeat for the other table you have.  Any reason why you'd need those cursors?

Answer (score 4):

You cannot perform DDL like CREATE TABLE directly in PL/SQL.  However, you can do it using dynamic PL/SQL like this:

```
-- vytovirt potrebne tabulky pre kosicke a nekosicke auta
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'CREATE TABLE Kosicke (
typ CHAR(10),
specifikacia_typu CHAR(15),
spz CHAR(8)
)';
```

Your inserts will also need to be dynamic, since the tables don't exist at compile time and so the code isn't valid:

```
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'INSERT INTO Ostatne VALUES(:p1, :p2, :p3)'
   USING my_typ, my_specifikacia_typu, my_spz;
```

It would be interesting to know why you need to do this, though: there is almost never any need to create tables "on the fly" in Oracle and it isn't generally a good idea to do so.

Answer (score 4):

Aside from your syntax issue, which Tony has explained, this code ought to just be straight SQL inserts without any cursors. If you really did need a cursor then try to use an implicit one before using an explicit one.

Comment: The cursors are there for SELECT queries. I have already solved this problem myself, I have posted the working program.